# How to retrieve width and height from video

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ffmpeg

How can i put to variables 'width' and 'height' video properties?
I have found something:

```
streaminfo=`mktemp`
ffprobe -v quiet -show_streams -select_streams v:0 input.mkv >$streaminfo
width=`grep width $streaminfo | cut -d'=' -f2`
height=`grep height $streaminfo | cut -d'=' -f2`
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use, for Bash

```
width=$(ffprobe -v quiet -show_entries stream=width -select_streams v:0 -of compact=p=0:nk=1 input.mkv)
height=$(ffprobe -v quiet -show_entries stream=height -select_streams v:0 -of compact=p=0:nk=1 input.mkv)
```

For CMD, on Windows

```
for /f %i in ('ffprobe -v quiet -show_entries "stream=width" -of "compact=p=0:nk=1" input.mkv') do set width=%i
for /f %i in ('ffprobe -v quiet -show_entries "stream=height" -of "compact=p=0:nk=1" input.mkv') do set height=%i
```